Xamarin Android API 34 (14) Failed to build in Visual Studio 2022
I need to update my Xamarin Project to the API 34 due to Google Play Policy. I have change targetSdkVersion to 34 but with no luck. I need to archive the project with format *.aab file before 1 Nov.
I got an error as below
Skipping target "_CompileToDalvik" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Creating "obj\Release\130\android\assets\shrunk\shrunk.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
The TargetFrameworkVersion (Android API level 33) is lower than the targetSdkVersion (34). Please increase the `$(TargetFrameworkVersion)` or decrease the `android:targetSdkVersion` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` so that the API levels match.
XABBA7024: Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipIOException: The file 'obj\Release\130\android\bin\base.zip' is not a ZIP archive.
   at Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipArchive.Open(String path, FileMode mode, String defaultExtractionDir, Boolean strictConsistencyChecks, IPlatformOptions options) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/LibZipSharp/Xamarin.Tools.Zip/ZipArchive.cs:line 282
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.ExecuteWithAbi(String[] supportedAbis, String apkInputPath, String apkOutputPath, Boolean debug, Boolean compress, IDictionary`2 compressedAssembliesInfo, String assemblyStoreApkName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.RunTask()
   at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17
Done building project "Project.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.

I have tried to

Make sure the API 34 downloaded successfully on the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms
Enable AndroidX Migrator (Experimental)
Trying to clean -> close project -> delete bin and obj folder and trying to re-opened the project. I still got the same issue.
Make sure my manifest already set targetSdkVersion to 34 both release and debug version
Trying running my VS2022 with Administrator Privilege.
Add <TargetFrameworkVersion>v14.0</TargetFrameworkVersion> on the .csproj file
Trying to replace the base zip file from SDK build 33 to 34 but with no luck
Updating SDK tools and build tools to the latest version
Create new blank project from template (Xamarin Project) and change to targetSdkVersion to 34 and still got the same error.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file, I just change the targetSdkVersion from 33 to 34 as below
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />

Finding:

If I changed back to API 33, everything turns normally. I can archive the aab file as normal.
If the error occurs, the base.zip files on the \obj\Release\130\android\bin will corrupted.
This issue occurs both on the release and debug mode.
The clean and build and rebuild process is success but the archive failed.
Both APK and AAB bundle format produce similar issue.

Android Version

Android SDK Plaftorm-tools v 34.0.3
Android SDK command-line tools v 7.0
Android SDK Build-tools 33.0.2

My Visual Studio version
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022
Version 17.6.4

I have read several article for this and no solution that works. Any idea?
Thank you

Please try installing the latest Visual Studio version 17.11.X, along with all the necessary components (SDK, etc.), and it should work!
Keep in mind that LTSC isn’t always the best option.
Cheers,
